# How to set matplotlib ax range positive and mirrored around a certian value

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a data and function with matplotlib 2.0 under python 2.7.

The x values of the function are evolving with time and the x is first decreasing to a certain value, than increasing again.

If the function is plotted against time, it shows function like this plot of data against time

[image: plot of data against time]

I need the same x axis evolution for plotting against real x values. Unfortunately as the x values are the same for both parts before and after, both values are mixed together. This gives me the wrong data plot:

[image]

In this example it means I need the x-axis to start on value 2.4 and decrease to 1.0 than again increase to 2.4. I swear I found before that this is possible, but unfortunately I can't find a trace about that again.

Comment: please add plot into the question body.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation for that.

Comment: It would be good to have a [mcve] of the issue. The solution would be to negate (multiply by (-1)) the values which should be on the left side of `1.0` in this case. How that can be done depends on the data you have and how it is stored.

Answer (score 2):

A matplotlib axis is by default linearly increasing. More importantly, there must be an injective mapping of the number line to the axis units. So changing the data range is not really an option (at least when the aim is to keep things simple).

It would hence be good to keep the original numbers and only change the ticks and ticklabels on the axis. E.g. you could use a `FuncFormatter` to map the original numbers to

```
np.abs(x-tp)+tp
```

where `tp` would be the turning point.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker

x = np.linspace(-10,20,151)
y = np.exp(-(x-5)**2/19.)

plt.plot(x,y)

tp = 5
fmt = lambda x,pos:"{:g}".format(np.abs(x-tp)+tp)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(fmt))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use two axes, and plot your two timespans separately on each axes.

for instance, if you have the following data:

```
myX = np.linspace(1,2.4,100)
myY1 = -1*myX
myY2 = -0.5*myX-0.5
plt.plot(myX,myY, c='b')
plt.plot(myX,myY2, c='g')
```

[image]

you can instead create two subplots with a shared y-axis and no space between the two axes, plot each time span independently, and finally, adjust the limits of one of your x-axis to reverse the order of the points

```
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, gridspec_kw={'wspace':0}, sharey=True)
ax1.plot(myX,myY1, c='b')
ax2.plot(myX,myY2, c='g')
ax1.set_xlim((2.4,1))
ax2.set_xlim((1,2.4))
```

[image]

Comment: This seems as a very good solution, even I am still wondered if this is possible to do within one ax.

Comment: It is sure possible within one axes as said in the comments above.